# Missing WordPress "Post Article" default menu, not the HTML one

Tags: html, wordpress, menu

I am missing the post menu from my wordpress site, I can only add bold, Italic, and underline with the HTML menu, that means with code.

I bought a plugin for post slides, and the plugin is shown only when the "normal" menu of the post is there, currently I have the HTML menu where you insert code into your articles.

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Try to disable plugin by plugin and then check which caused the problem.

Comment: I disabled all the plugins, and the issue is still there. I remember I installed a theme called AlbinoMouse and after that the post menu disappeared. I deleted the theme and the issue is still there.

Comment: Try to update Wordpress. Clear your cache and try with another browser too.

Comment: I did what you said and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What is your website? And what template do you use?

Comment: Website is: outfitideas.org and the theme is: newscore 1.6

Comment: Ok. Please wait a bit. I am checking.

Comment: Case 1 solved the issue, I left a comment on answer. Thanks again NETCreator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1:** Go to Users > Your Profile and uncheck "Disable the visual editor when writing".

**Case 2:** If the problem prospers, then try to select another default template. If the problem is solved the check your functions.php file of the template, because it caused the problem.

**Case 3:** There could be a problem from one of your plugins. Deactivate them all and try again.

Hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you. Case 1 solved my issue. Wish you a good day NETCreator.